# Regex - capture multiple groups and combine them multiple times in one string

Tags: regex, ruby

I need to combine some text using regex, but I'm having a bit of trouble when trying to capture and substitute my string. For example - I need to capture digits from the start, and add them in a substitution to every section closed between ||

I have:

```
||10||a||ab||abc||
```

I want:

```
||10||a10||ab10||abc10||
```

So I need '10' in capture group 1 and 'a|ab|abc' in capture group 2

I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work for me (captures only one [a-z] group)

```
(?=.*\|\|(\d+)\|\|)(?=.*\b([a-z]+\b))
```

Comment: You can't do it properly without an infinite-width lookbehind or some extra code. Is it used in C#?

Comment: Do you always have exactly 4 values in between pipes, per line?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - no, there can be more or less values

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I'm testing it here: https://rubular.com/r/W9wslP5auYiqAu - so ruby I guess? It doesn't have to be "clean" - after substitution I can remove first section with digits - I just need this digits to be combined with every other section

Comment: I don't know/use Ruby, but I would suggest just extracting the first value, then splitting your string on `||`, and finally piecing it back together.

Comment: Something like [this](https://ideone.com/Ue6PFh) might be a good start.

Answer (score 2):

I would achieve this without a complex regular expression. For example, you could do this:

```
input = "||10||a||ab||abc||"
parts = input.scan(/\w+/)   # => ["10", "a", "ab", "abc"]
parts[1..-1].each { |part| part << parts[0] }   # => ["a10", "ab10", "abc10"]

"||#{parts.join('||')}||"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "||10||a||ab||abc||"
```

```
first = nil
str.gsub(/(?<=\|\|)[^\|]+/) { |s| first.nil? ? (first = s) : s + first }
  #=> "||10||a10||ab10||abc10||"
```

The regular expression reads, "match one or more characters in a pipe immediately following two pipes" (`(?<=\|\|)` being a *positive lookbehind*).